# Some numbers take longer to factor than others

Tags: c, primes

Can someone tell me the reason that the number 104751475143 is computed in less than a second while the number 251475141 takes a longer amount of time? The code is trying to find the largest factor.

This is my code.

```
    long long lrgPFactor = 0;
    long long currentfactor = 0;
    long long tempfactor = 0;
    long long Number =  251475141;
    long long factor = 0;


    switch ((long long)sqrt(Number)%2) //skipping to the square root of the number to save time
{ 
    case 0: factor=((long long)sqrt(Number)-1); break; //If even make it odd
    default: factor=((long long)sqrt(Number)); break; //If odd leave it
}
    while (factor > 0) 
{
        if (Number % factor == 0) //if factor is a factor
       {
            factor=Number/factor; //make the factor the larger of the pair
        switch ((long long)sqrt(factor)%2) //same as above
            { 
                case 0: tempfactor=((long long)sqrt(factor)-1); break; 
                default: tempfactor=((long long)sqrt(factor)); break; 
            }  
            for (tempfactor = factor - 1; tempfactor > 1; --tempfactor) //simple way to determine if prime
            {
            if (factor % tempfactor == 0)
                    break;
            }
            if (tempfactor == 1)
            {
               lrgPFactor = factor;
               break;
           }
        }
        factor -= 2;
}
```

Comment: Maybe because `104751475143` has a lot more small factors to pull out?

Comment: "Some numbers take longer to factor than others" - exactly, did you expect that you can factor every possible number within the same amount of time?

Comment: @H2CO3 well I thought larger numbers would take longer. It seems it mostly has to do with how close the prime is to the square root in my instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes longer because the prime factor of 104751475143 is 391751 and 104751475143/391751=267393 which is closer to the square root of 104751475143 than 3 (3=251475141/83825047) is close to the square root of 251475151. So it must run through more iterations of the loop.